# Can You Create Free Rent Agreements in Monopoly

Tags: monopoly

Is it legal to allow free rent agreements as part of a real estate transaction in Monopoly?  Specifically I'd like to purchase a property and sell two additional properties but only if both parties in the transaction receive 'free rent' as long as we own the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can offer a rent free situation by promising the player that you will never claim rent.  As rent is only ever paid when the owner of a property claims it, you can in effect offer free rent.

There is no way to enforce this though and you must treat this as nothing more than a gentleperson's agreement.

Comment: You cannot offer free rent to any player under any circumstance.  I specifically remember reading this on a questions & answer listing on a cardboard insert of a Monopoly game.